# How to get all users with individual related objects in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to output all users with their related scores

```
user = User.objects.all()
scores = user.myuser.all()
```

Where 'myuser' is a related name of the scores model, I tried the above code but I was getting this error:

> myuser is not an attribute of the objects error.

Comment: could you post your models please?

Comment: class studentscores(models.Model):
           user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='myuser')
class = models.CharField(max_length=50)
subjects = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use dictionary to store users and scores, you can do it directly from the user's object.

**In view.py:**

```
def index(request):
    users = user.objects.all()
    return render(request,'template_name.html',{'users':users})
```

**In Django template:**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for score in user.studentscores_set.all %}
        <p>{{ score.field_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I added if statement inside the for loops because I want to separate the scores in different terms, but it is not showing, please can u help with that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of you're model names, but something like this should work:
Assuming you have something along the lines of:

```
class StudentScores(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

To get all the scores for a single user:

```
scores = user.studentscores_set.all()
```

To iterate over all users and their scores:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    for score in user.studentscores_set.all():
        print(score)
```

When you have a foreign key relation, you can access them from the related model (in this case `User`), using `<name>_set.all()` syntax.

You can probably do something more efficient with annotated querysets but without knowing the use case for this it's a bit more difficult to recommend anything more.

NOTE:
If you've defined a `related_name` for the `user` field in scores (like this:
`user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='scores'`), then you can access the scores for a user like this: `scores = user.scores.all()`

Also, I noticed you had a field `class = models.CharField()`, please consider renaming this to something else e.g. `student_class` as `class` is a reserved word.

Comment: K, thank you, but how can I place the total users and scores in dictionary after iterating?, I want to create a dictionary then output them on my template.